# How to send <h3> and <p> elements in a button to another page using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm doing the following, however it's returning `undefined` for each the `header` and the `parapgraph` sent

`Careers.html`

```
    //Javascript code
    var jobButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
    var jobTitles = document.getElementsByClassName("button_title");
    var jobSubtitles = document.getElementsByClassName("subtitle");

    jobButtons[0].addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
        var title = jobTitles[0].value;
        var subtitle = jobSubtitles[0].value;
   
        localStorage.setItem("job_header", title);
        localStorage.setItem("job_subheader", subtitle);

        window.location.replace("CareerOffer.html");
    })
```

`CareerOffers.html`

```
        //Javascript code
        document.getElementById("job_header").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("job_header");
        document.getElementById("job_subheader").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("job_subheader");
```

Comment: You probably want to use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML` unless you're actually injecting raw HTML strings (which you don't seem to be doing, you're just moving text content around). That said: set dev tools to preserve the log across page nagivations, and then console log `localStorage` before you replace the URL in careers, and then console log it again in careeroffers. And while this should go without saying, I'll say it anyway: "and make sure you're testing with an actual server, not by just loading files in the browser".

Comment: I tried using `.textContent` and `.innerText` but none of which worked

Comment: The problem is maybe from your html. Can you edit your question with the html

Comment: @Little_Dev what do you mean by "Can you edit your question with the html"

Comment: You say that `title` is a `<h3>` and that `subtitle` is a `<p>`, but these don't have a `.value`! Use `.textContent` there as well.

Comment: You really should use a `<form>` with a submit button and url query values, not a `mousedown` handler and `localstorage`.